# display full tagged entries in emacs org-mode agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using org-journal in emacs (Windows). I tag some of the journal entries. Is there an easy way to display all of the full entries (i.e. the headline and the following entry) for a certain tag in a certain time frame? It is quite easy to display the headlines for a certain tag in agenda view (http://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-searches.html#Tag-searches), but I would like the full entry in the same buffer (mostly for export or printing).